# Proxy to API on another dyno with Heroku

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have my API on one dyno and my front end on another dyno.

I am unsure how to access the api dyno.

Example:

```
web: yarn --cwd web start -p $PORT
api: bundle exec rails s -p 3001
```

Then a proxy:

```
const apiProxy = createProxyMiddleware({
    target: 'http://127.0.0.1:3001',
    changeOrigin: true,
    pathRewrite: { [`^/api/graphql`]: '' },
    secure: false,
});

export default function (req, res) {
    apiProxy(req, res, (result) => {
        if (result instanceof Error) {
            throw result;
        }

        throw new Error(`Request '${req.url}' is not proxied! We should never reach here!`);
    });
};
```

It doesn't seem to be this straight forward though.

Answer (score 0):

Once the API component is deployed on a Web Dyno you should use the host assigned by Heroku, for example `myapi.herokuapp.com`.
The endpoint to invoke is then `https://myapi.herokuapp.com`

Comment: Thank you for this. However this would require 2 apps... I was hoping to deploy both onto one app with 2 dynos. The problem I am facing is that there is no reference (IP Address or otherwise) to the API dyno.

Comment: You need 2 different dynos as every dyno exposes on port. You can deploy the same apps twice but each app must expose either the api or the frontend (effectively 2 apps but the same code). One option is to wrap both apps in the same package (standard approach if you have React and Java), not sure how you can do that with Ruby